# Django - Model class django_otp.plugins.otp_static.models.StaticDevice doesn't declare an explicit app_label

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/percipient/django-allauth-2fa/blob/master/allauth_2fa/views.py). When i imported the views on my own **urls.py** using: `from allauth_2fa import views` i got the following error:

```
   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Heroku\github\backup\main\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from allauth_2fa import views
  File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\allauth_2fa\views.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django_otp.plugins.otp_static.models import StaticToken
  File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django_otp\plugins\otp_static\models.py", line 11, in <module>
    class StaticDevice(Device):
  File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 95, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django_otp.plugins.otp_static.models.StaticDevice doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

I don't understand if i'm doing something wrong, or the error is in the dependency module. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some process you miss. You did not add the `allauth_2fa` in INSTALLED_APPS and not migrate it. I try to write the full process its configuration.

**Step 1 :**

`pip install django-allauth-2fa`

**Step 2 :**

apply those in settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # Required by allauth.
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Configure Django auth package.
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',

    # Enable allauth.
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',

    # Configure the django-otp package.
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',

    # Enable two-factor auth.
    'allauth_2fa',
)
```

**Step 3:**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Configure Django auth package.
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',

    # Configure the django-otp package. Note this must be after the
    # AuthenticationMiddleware.
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',

    # Reset login flow middleware. If this middleware is included, the login
    # flow is reset if another page is loaded between login and successfully
    # entering two-factor credentials.
    'allauth_2fa.middleware.AllauthTwoFactorMiddleware',
)
# Set the allauth adapter to be the 2FA adapter.
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'allauth_2fa.adapter.OTPAdapter'
```

**Step 4:**

```
python manage.py migrate
```

**Step 5 :**

Now you can import it in your views file
also must configure in urls.py file

If face any problem comment below

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately i'm fairly new to Django and i don't think that those things you told me to add were specified in their docs! It's working now!

Comment: Its great pleasure for me that your problem is now solve